# Dart can't access property on a generic type function parameter despite providing the type

Tags: dart, generics

I'm trying to specify a function parameter as a generic type `T`:

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo,
  Bar
}

class DbColumn {
  final Function<T>(T value) serializer;
  const DbColumn({this.serializer});
}

class MyClass {

  static final DbColumn rating = DbColumn(
    serializer: <MyEnum>(v) {
      var i = v.index;
    }
  );
}
```

However when trying to access `index` on `v` I get this type error message:

> The getter 'index' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'index', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'index'.

When I hover over `v` in VSC it says that it's of type `MyEnum`.

If I instead remove the generic type and do a cast like this it works as expected:

```
class DbColumn {
  final Function(dynamic value) serializer;
  const DbColumn({this.serializer});
}

class MyClass {
  static final DbColumn rating = DbColumn(
    serializer: (v) {
      var casted = v as MyEnum;
      var i = casted.index;
    }
  );
}
```

Why is the generic type not working as expected?

**EDIT:**

What is even weirder is that this example works too if I put it inside `MyClass`:

```
  x<T>(Function(T) c) {}

  y() {
    x<MyEnum>((v) {
      print(v.index); // No error given and type of v is MyEnum
    });
  }
```

**EDIT 2**: The same problem happens when overriding methods:

```
abstract class MyInterface {
  int someFunction<T>(T value);
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  @override
  someFunction<MyEnum>(v) {
    return v.index; // Gives same error and no intellisense happens in VSC
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of making the function generic, declare the class as generic and it will work as expected. Like this :**

```
enum MyEnum {
  Foo,
  Bar
}

class DbColumn<T> {
  final Function(T value) serializer;
  const DbColumn({this.serializer});
}

class MyClass {

  static final DbColumn<MyEnum> rating = DbColumn(
    serializer: (v) {
      var i = v.index;
      print('Index : $i');
    }
  );
}

void main() {
 MyClass.rating.serializer(MyEnum.Bar);
}
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Index : 1
```

Comment: Yeah this was the official solution from someone on GitHub as well. Although I didn't understand why I need to make the class generic instead of the function.. Mind giving me an explanation?

Comment: The explanation is that when you write `<MyEnum>(v) ...` and assign it to something declared as `final Function<T>(T value) serializer;`, inference converts the first function to `<MyEnum>(MyEnum v) { ... }` where `MyEnum` is the name of the type variable. It's completely equivalent to `<X>(X v) { ... }`, you've just renamed the variable. You cannot do `v.index` because the bound of `X` has no `index` member. The error message is confusing because you have two types named `MyEnum` - the original, and the type variable, but they are really different types with the same name.